# Reading A Massive CSV file into an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql

I have this huge CSV file that has over 200,000 lines. each line has a review ID, Hotel ID, Review Date and the review itself. The review column is causing issues. Some of the reviews are very long, longer than 2000 bytes so it is causing an error:

> ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes.

Is there anything i can do to move past this issue? Here is my current code:

```
DECLARE
    F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    v_Line VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_ReviewID NUMBER;
    v_HotelID VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_ReviewDate VARCHAR(2000);
    v_ReviewName CLOB;
    v_Review CLOB;
BEGIN
    F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('REVIEW_READ', 'Review.csv', 'R', 30000);

    IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start');
                UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F, v_Line);            
                v_ReviewID    := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_Line, '[^,]+', 1, 1);
                v_HotelID     := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_Line, '[^,]+', 1, 2);
                v_ReviewDate  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_Line, '[^,]+', 1, 3); 
                v_ReviewName  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_Line, '[^,]+', 1, 4);
                v_Review      := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_Line, '[^,]+', 1, 5);

                INSERT INTO Review
                VALUES(v_ReviewID, v_HotelID, v_ReviewDate, v_ReviewName, v_Review);

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_Line);

                IF v_Line IS NULL THEN
                    EXIT;
                END IF;

                COMMIT;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    EXIT;
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS THEN  
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
END;
```

Comment: Please mention the database software you're using: Oracle ?

Comment: Yes I am using Oracal

Comment: Change the data type of the review text to `CLOB`.

Comment: I made the above edits but i still revived the following error:ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes. The reviews are mixed lengths and some are really big. Is there a way to read part of it then Parse it then read the rest?

Comment: @NathanC I have added this error message to your question. I assume that is the main one you were hitting since you refer to "a buffer overflow error", though there may also be issues if the VARCHAR2 variables or the table's columns aren't big enough for what you're loading into them. It's also a good idea to use `tablename.columnname%type` syntax when declaring columns so you know everything is in sync.

Comment: hi., 2lakh lines is not massive; when all plsql fails...
if you can use excel to open this file; frame insert statement using concatenate 
and directly save and execute them as sql file from sqlplus CLI

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 issues with your code. One was already mentioned by @Steve Friedl. And the other one is as below:

`ORU-10027` will appear if you are using a lot of `dbms_output.put_line` in your `PL/SQL` with a small buffer amount. 
If you are just debugging then you should set this to a large amount (dbms_output.enable(10000000) is traditional though from 10g onwards it can be unlimted.

So in your code if you comment this line
`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_LINE);`  and put this `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start');` out of loop, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this DB system, but it seems like this line:

```
v_Review  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^,]+', 1, 5);
```

is giving you the problems by trying to assign a too-long string to the 2000-limit `v_Review`.  Perhaps the use of `SUBSTR` to collect only the first 2000 characters of this string might work?

```
v_Review  := SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^,]+', 1, 5), 0, 2000 ); // maybe?
```

Comment: This did not work. I still ended up getting the same error:                                         ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 20000 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all your `dbms_output` lines and recheck the result. My guess is that you just put a very long output to buffer.
Also if you have to load a one-time CSV file into Oracle Database have a look at `sqlldr` utility (https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ, for example). It does all the job for you, you just create a target table and do some settings.